# File type associated icons package for flutter?

Tags: flutter, icons, pub.dev

I have searched but can't find anything or don't know how to find this. Is there an existing flutter package that has icons for common file types? If I'm displaying a file list, I'd like to show associated icons for those files such as .txt, .exe, .jpg, and just about anything else you'd find on a desktop computer, if possible.

It may not be possible to get the actual associated icon. For instance, a .jpg could be associated with multiple apps but I'd be fine with just a generic .jpg file icon for this or any other file type. I just don't want to show the same material icon for every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

https://pub.dev/packages/file_icon

Please note that the package is not maintained.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that package but thought it was for coding type icons only.